# Google SEO Site Map submitted but no pages have been indexed

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I have submitted the sitemap for my website more than two weeks ago.

Altogether there are 12 pages in the site map. Under crawls- sitemaps, in google webmaster tools there is 12 submitted and 7 indexed shown, but if I go to google index- index status it shows 0 indexed, and no content keywords data showing.

Do I need to re-submit the sitemap or need to make any changes, my sitemap is accessible on the following location.

```
www.trialsgate.com/GSiteMap.xml
```

Comment: Submitting a sitemap does not guarantee inclusion in Googe's index

Comment: i am not too sure john what you mean by off topic because topic is google seo

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In this case the question has already been asked and answered there: [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content)

Answer (score 2):

Write this:

```
site:trialsgate.com
```

in [Google.com](http://google.com) to check the number of pages indexed by Google (the fresh index).

P.S. The result of the above mentioned query does show that 10 of your site's pages have been indexed indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I checked your sitemap, it's right.

Google does not guarantee that index your sitemap links.

sometimes number of indexes are not correct, specially when the website is small. best thing you can do and yet the correct way is to google this to make sure how many of your pages are indexed and how:

site:trialsgate.com

at this time 10 pages of your website are already indexed.

tip: make sure you add both trialsgate.com and www.trialsgate.com to google webmaster.

Answer (score 0):

i have same experience as per your question but that time i have started strong marketing means social media, bookmarking, guest blogging from high DA sites with proper linking.

after doing this, site will crawl automatically within 1 week.

try this may be this is your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your URL manually in [GOOGLE SEARCH CONSOLE](https://search.google.com/search-console/)

1. Go to the google search console
2. Go to left hand side on URL inspection
3. Then, add your URL
4. And, Submit the URL

(Also you can check the indexed URL as well)